# How to get a string[] array into a DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new to C#.

I have different file names. for example:

> C:\Test\ABCD\Warranty_2018_02_12__13_25_13.743.xml

from this name I want to get the date, like **12.02.2018 13:25:13**

So the files are never the same.

My code:

```
        public string GetCreationDate(string fileResult)
    {
        int index = fileResult.IndexOf("_");
        if (index != -1)
        {
            string date = fileResult.Substring(index + 1, 20);
            char[] delimiter = new char[] { '_' };

            string[] dateWithoutLines = date.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Array.Reverse(dateWithoutLines, 0, 3);

            //Here is the error
            //Guess it's because of the 'ToString()' 
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateWithoutLines.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return dateTime.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In the debugger I have now 6 strings in the **dateWithoutLines** with the right dates. like "12" "02" "2018" ...

But then it says that is it not a right DateTime Format there. Okay, but if I delete the

> ToString()

It says it can't convert string[] to string. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to split the original string, reverse, combine and so on.

Let `DateTime.TryParseExact` do all the work for you:

Also, consider returning a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) instead of a string:

```
public DateTime? GetCreationDate(string fileResult)
{
    int index = fileResult.IndexOf("_");
    if (index <= 0)
        return null;

    // check for string length, you don't want the following call to fileResult.Substring to throw an exception
    if (fileResult.Length < index+20)
        return null;

    string date = fileResult.Substring(index + 1, 20);

    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dateWithoutLines` is a `string[]`. The `ToString` implementation for `string[]` yields *"System.String[]"* which is not a valid date. Furthermore `DateTime.Parse` does not take a `string[]`, but only a string.

If the date format in the file name is always the same, you can use `string.Format`

```
var formattedDate = string.Format("{2}.{1}.{0} {3}:{4}:{5}", dateWithoutLines);
```

The numbers in the curly braces refer objects in the passed array by index, i.e. that `{2}` will be replaced by `12` in your example, `{1}` by `02` and so on. **Please note** that I've used the indices from the original order, not the reversed array.

Since you're parsing the date to format it, this way, no parsing is needed, since it's already formatted.

Comment: ah thank you! This works! So here I dont have to give the strings to a DateTime constructor?

Comment: You could format the strings to something `DateTime.Parse` understands and return a `DateTime` instead of a `string`, which would be better if you are doing more with the date than outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

object instance `dateWithoutLines`  is an array of strings , not a single string, thus you cant use  method `ToString()`.

So I believe you want something in the sense of :

```
foreach (string date in dateWithoutLines)
{
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Notice, that since you have an array of strings, date is a string object so there is no need to call `ToString()` method for each `date` string instance

Comment: Yeah, but here is the same error, it says that the DateTime is not in a right format.